# How can we Move the file from an S3 to EC2 using Lambda on daily basis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

How can we Move the file from an S3 to EC2 using Lambda on daily basis ?

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with using an AWS Lambda function to copy a file to an Amazon EC2 instance is that the Lambda function must gain access to the EC2 instance.

It is much simpler for some code on the EC2 instance to **pull the file from Amazon S3**.

You could:

- Create a script on the EC2 instance to copy the file
- Configure a `cron` job (or Windows Scheduled Task) to run the script at the desired time

The script would use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), such as:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/foo.txt /local-dir/foo.txt
```

Presumably you are copying the file to the EC2 instance to do some further processing, so this scheduled script could then trigger the code that will process the file.